# Passar $route como parametro para uma função Vue JS

Tags: html5, vue.js, vue-router

É possível passar `$route` como parâmetro para uma função?

```
<v-btn color="info" v-on:click="getProximo('this.$route')">
    Próximo
</v-btn>
```

Preciso pegar um parâmetro que está em `$route`, porém ao usar `this.$route.params.NomeParametro` dentro da função `getProximo()` não funciona, teria como passar como parametro ao chamar a função no `click` do botão?

Comment: Testa somente `v-on:click="getProximo($route)">`

Comment: @Sergio funcionou!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o `$store` é uma propriedade do componente podes usar assim:

```
<v-btn color="info" v-on:click="getProximo($route)">
  Próximo
</v-btn>
```

Ou então usar `v-on:click="getProximo"` e depois dentro do método:

```
methods: {
    getProximo(event){
        const route = this.$route;
        // etc...
    }
```